# How to lookup data on Stateful Services in other ways than using Key

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

I've read all the Azure Service Fabric articles that I can find, but I still can't get my head around how you're suppose to work with the data that you store in your Stateful Services - other than by fetching them by key.

E.g. Let's say that I have a `Team` and a `Player` object. They are stored in `IReliableDictionaries` with key `team-1`, `team-2` and `player-1`, `player-2` etc.

Each `Player` object has a `Player.team` value that is a reference to the `Team`.

Now... Let's say that I want to get all stored `Player` objects that have `Player.team` equal to `team-2`. How do I do this? Do I have to manually loop through all my objects and find all myself? Shouldn't there be filter functions when you fetch the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop through the data using `CreateEnumerableAsync` and `GetAsyncEnumerator`. Use with care, this can take some time if your dictionary is large. And it's not an efficient way to search a collection. (opposed to using the key)

You could also store references from Player to Team and from Team to Player. Modify both `ReliableDictionaries` inside a [Transaction](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-work-with-reliable-collections/) to keep them in sync. This way you can find Teams for a Player and Players for a Team without looping. Make sure that you keep your State objects immutable like shown in the linked article.

You can also keep a third dictionary that holds all the references between Team and Player objects, so you don't clutter your object model too much if you have many references.

Finally, you could use an external store like SQL Server if you need to query lots of relational data.